# What can load private native libraries on Android N+?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I have to load some hardware exclusive non-NDK (i.e. private) platform native libraries in my application; due to a long dependency chain and differences in individual device implementations, bundling copies of the native libraries per [Google's advice](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#ndk-update) is not practical.  Since the libraries are hardware specific, they can't be added to the [NDK or VNDK](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/namespaces_libraries.html).

Since even system apps are no longer allowed to load private native libs, I'm not sure what Android component would be able to.  I found out by accident that apps installed and running from /system/priv-app seem to get a pass because /system/lib is considered to be on their library search path, but updates to them installed in the usual /data partition lose that access (so a stub privileged app with later updates is not an option).  I would prefer to avoid having a non-updateable /system/priv-app solution, and anyway I haven't found this workaround documented anywhere so I doubt it's an official and reliable alternative.

I have access to the full system source code for my devices, so adding framework modules is a fine solution; however, I'm not sure what constitutes 'framework code' in this context and/or would have access to private native libs on Android N+.

**What components of Android have access to private native libs?**

**Would a system service discoverable via ServiceManager and Context.getSystemService() have access to private native libs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aiui this is what the VNDK is for.

> What components of Android have access to private native libs?

System services. Not apps; normal programs.

Comment: The VNDK might have been a great solution, but Android 8 added the limitation that "The library, either directly or transitively via its dependencies, must not depend on system libraries other than VNDK-SP and LLNDK libraries. The list of VNDK-SP and LLNDK libraries can be found at development/vndk/tools/definition/tool/datasets/eligible-list-<version>-release.csv."  I'm not certain, but I think the eligible list is defined upstream by Google and modifications would cause CTS to fail.

Comment: Do you know why system services and android executables are able to load private native libs whereas apps cannot?  The message "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library ... needed or dlopened by
"/system/lib/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace
"classloader-namespace"" is not very clear, and the namespaces doc [https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/namespaces_libraries.html] doesn't get into details.